# IBM.Data.DB2.Core DataReader.GetSchemaTable() method throws NotSupportedException C# .NET standard

Tags: c#, datatable, db2, datareader, getschematable

Code is in C# .NET standard

```
var connectionString = $"<connection string here>";
var connection = new DB2Connection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
string sqlStatement = "<a valid query goes here>";
command.CommandText = sqlStatement;
IDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

var data = new DataTable();
data = dataReader.GetSchemaTable(); //This throws a NotSupportedException.
//data.Load(dataReader); //This should work, but the above line is what throws the exception, which is what this method is calling internally.
```

A NotSupportedException is thrown on the last line that is not commented out, with the message 'Specified method is not supported.'

I have version 1.2.2.100 of IBM.Data.DB2.Core installed, and the version 11.1 license as well.
If you need any more context let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, may be you should try to compile this sample in order to validate your version and installation : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/dotnet_cs/s-DbDatAdp-cs.html

Comment: That code doesn't compile when using the  IBM.Data.DB2.Core NuGet package. It compiles with the old  IBM.Data.DB2 package. But I need this to work in a .NET Standard environment.

Comment: Your code fragment (with a suitable connection string and query) works for me with Db2-LUW v11.1.3.3a and Visual-Studio-2017-community-edition(15.7.6).  If you still have a problem, you might update your question to give precise environment/component details.

Comment: I have the same issue. Versions are netcoreapp2.1, using DB2 1.2.2.100 on Mac OS X. Looks like this is not implemented by IBM.

Answer (score -1):

You query select dont have join, only one table.

I propose you my code which use IDB2 objects :

```
var connectionString = $"<connection string here>";
string sqlStatement = "<a valid query goes here>";

var connection = new DB2Connection(connectionString);
DB2Command myCommand = new DB2Command(sqlStatement,connection);

connection.Open();

try 
{
  DB2DataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

  DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();

  reader.Close();
}
finally 
{
  connection .Close();
}
```